# Why is document.write missing in custom document objects?

Tags: javascript

Create custom document object:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(
  'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
  'html',
  //Inherit current doctype
  document.doctype
);
```

Try to write in it:

```
//Throws error - TypeError: doc.write is not a function
doc.write(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Same goes for `.close` and `.open`. What the hell? Is this a bug? Probably not - all browsers do it:

**Chrome** (most helful error ever, Chrome must be fun to debug in):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**Opera:**

```
TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'write'
```

**Firefox:**

```
TypeError: document.implementation.createDocument(...).write is not a function
```

Why are the methods `open`, `write` and `close` missing for custom documents?

Comment: My guess would be because `.write`, `.open` and `.close` are horrible methods and should not be used?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with that `doc`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why are they horrible? Do you propose better solution to the whole problem?

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm loading HTML dynamically, then copying certain node values to the loaded `window.document`. I'm trying to load `next` and `previous` comics using AJAX and preload them so that I don't have to wait... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.implementation.createDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createDocument) returns a [`XMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument).
However, [`.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.write) is a function [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) [inherits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document#Extension_for_HTML_documents) from [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument).

Basically, `XMLDocument`s don't have that function.
You're probably looking for [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument)

Comment: I'd really like to create HTMLDocument then.

Comment: Have a look at [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument)

Comment: According to MDN, `XMLDocument` inherits from `Document` which has the `.write` and other.

Comment: @TomášZato: _"It inherits from the generic `Document` and does not add any specific methods or properties to it"_ _"This interface doesn't inherit any method."_